# How to validate Extjs Editable Grid Cell

Tags: validation, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

I have an editable grid and for a particular column / field I have to implement validation. For example lets say I have a grid with 2 columns. Want to validate the symbol once enter a symbol and its quantity.

For validation there will be a service call and the response will have an indicator and based on that Will set the background of Invalid symbol to RED.

[image]

How can I send AJAX request and mark invalid symbol with Border color red / bgcolor red

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cell editing you can use `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` grid plugin. This plugin have `edit( editor, context, eOpts )` event which is fired after cell was edited.

In listener for this event, you can get information about edited record from `context` parameter and make AJAX request to server for validation.

For set background color of the grid cell you can use:

```js
// get element object from HTML code
var rowEl = Ext.get(context.row);
var tdElIdx =  context.colIdx + 1;
// find element of edited cell
var celEl = rowEl.down('td:nth(' + tdElIdx + ')');
// set background color of the cell
celEl.setStyle('background-color','red');
```